# Is taking limits in this proof really necessary?

Tags: proof-verification, banach-algebras

Consider the following proof:

> ￼**Theorem.** *Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra and $a$ an element of $A$ such that $\Vert a \Vert < 1$. Then $1 - a \in \operatorname{Inv}(A)$ and*
>   $$(1-a)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n.$$
>   *Proof*. Since
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Vert a^n\Vert \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Vert a \Vert^n = \left(1-\Vert a \Vert\right)^{-1} < + \infty,$$
>   the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n$ is convergent, to $b$ say, in $A$, and since $$\left(1-a\right) (1+\cdots+a^n) = 1 - a^{n+1}$$
>   converges to $\left(1-a\right) b = b \left(1-a\right)$ and to $1$ as $n \to \infty$, the element $b$ is the inverse of $1 - a$. $\square$

I am wondering about whether it is correct to argue as follows instead:

Since $\sum a^n$ is convergent the multiplication $a \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n$ and the subtraction $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n  - \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n = 1$ are justified. Therefore $\left(1-a\right)b = 1$.

Comment: The fact that you can put $a$ inside the infinite sum requires a proof: continuity of the multiplication, plus the definition of the infinite sum as the limit of the partial sums.

Comment: @Etienne Could you please elaborate on why this basic fact about infinite series in $\mathbb R$ does not generalize to Banach spaces?

Comment: Just to be clear: by basic fact I mean that if $\sum_n a_n$ converges where $a_n \in \mathbb R$ then for $c \in \mathbb R$ it holds that $c \sum a_n = \sum ca_n$ and all the other convenient limit theorems also apply.

Comment: This basic fact does generalize, of course; and the proof is the same as for real-valued series.

Comment: @Etienne Got it, thanks! Without the taking limits step one has to show that these algebraic limit properties familiar from $\mathbb R$ also hold in any Banach space.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the point.

Comment: @Etienne Can you please tell me if the following is correct:

Comment: First, for $c \in A$: $ c a_n \to  c a$: $$\\ \\$$
Let $c \in A$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $$ \|ca - c a_n \| = \|c\| \|a_n - a\|$$ hence if we choose $N$ such that $n >N$ implies $\|a_n - a\|<{\varepsilon \over \|c\|}$ we have $ \|ca - c a_n \| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Second, if $b_n, b \in A$ with $b_n  \to b$ then $(a_n + b_n) \to a + b$: $$\\ \\$$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $$ \| (a+b) - (a_n + b_n)\| \le \|a-a_n\| + \|b-b_n\|$$ hence for $N = \max (N_a,N_b)$ where $N_a$ and $N_b$ make each term smaller than ${\varepsilon \over 2}$ respectively it follows that $ \| (a+b) - (a_n + b_n)\| <\varepsilon$.

Comment: Third, combine the two:

Let $a \in A$ such that $\|a\| < 1$. Then $$ \left \|{1 \over 1- a} \right \|  = \left \| \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n \right \| \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty \|a\|^n < \infty$$ hence
$(1-a)^{-1}\in A$. Furthermore, 
$$ (1-a)(1-a)^{-1} =  \sum_{n\ge0} a^n- a \sum_{n\ge0} a^n = \sum_{n\ge0} a^n -  \sum_{n \ge 1}a^n = 1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: this is an answer to the above series of comments by Student. It was too long for a comment.

OK for "first" and "second". For "third", you shouldn't start by writing down $\frac1{1-a}$, since you precisely want to show that this exists. (By the way, the notation $\frac1{1-a}$ is usually "forbidden" in a vector-valued setting: it is generally agreed that one "must" write $(1-a)^{-1}$).

Likewise, you shouldn't write $\sum_0^\infty a_n$ as long as you don't know that the series is indeed convergent in $A$. So: start by proving that the series $\sum\Vert a^n\Vert$ is convergent (as you did). Then deduce that the series $\sum a^n$ is convergent in $A$ (because $A$ is a *Banach* algebra), and finally check as you did that $b=\sum_0^\infty a^n$ satisfies $(1-a)b=1=b(1-a)$, so that $1-a$ is indeed invertible with inverse $b$.

Final remark: part "second" is in fact never used.